# Number of ways to arrange 5 boys and 3 girls around a circular table such that no girls are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

[This is not a duplicate question - please read my approach to the solution.]

Question: Number of ways to arrange 5 boys and 3 girls so that no girls are adjacent in a circular arrangement.

My Approach:

1/ Total number of ways to arrange without any restrictions = `7!`

2/ Total number of ways to arrange in which all girls sit together = `5!*3!` [`5!` - because, I consider all girls to be one entity, thus making total unique entities as 6 and `3!` because, those 3 girls can be, amongst themselves, be arranged in `3!` ways]

The answer should be `7! - 5!3! = 5040 - 720 = 4320`.

However, the correct answer is `1440`. Where is my calculation wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

You misread the question; cases where exactly two are together should be discounted. We can use one specific girl as a reference point, then one boy must go on either side ($5×4=20$ ways), then it remains to arrange $2$ girls and three boys in a line such that the girls are not together ($5!-2×4!=72$ ways), giving $1440$ ways in all.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry - I wrote the question incorrectly - it is about having "no girls adjacent". Kindly help me with this.

Comment: @prabodhprakash You have still misread the question.

Comment: "no girls adjecent" - does it not mean (1) all three girls must not be together (2) any two girl must not be together

Comment: new learner to combinatorics, an elaborate answer to reading such question will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

With a "head boy" at the "north" seat, seat the boys in $4!$ ways

The girls can now be seated in the $5$ *gaps* between the boys in $P_3^5 $ ways.

Putting the pieces together, $4!\times P_3^5 = 24\cdot 60 =1440$ ways

Comment: "No girls adjacent" in a circular arrangement means that each girl must have a boy on both sides of her.